# Embedded SSRS permissions error using rsweb:ReportViewer

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2019

We have a ASP.Net Web forms application that has embedded SSRS reports and we are trying to upgrade from SQL SSRS 2008 to 2019. With SSRS 2008 we just used an iframe to embed the reports but it looks like this isn't supported anymore so have moved to using the rs:WebReportViewer component. The site relies on ASP.NET Impersonation authentication but with this turned on I'm getting 401 errors in the report viewer. If we turn impersonation off the report loads but this breaks the rest of the ASP.NET application.

Is there a way to use rs:WebReportViewer within a site that uses ASP.NET Impersonation?

[image: Error]

[image: IIS Authentication settings]